# Distribution of logistic regression estimators

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, linear-regression, logistic-regression

It is well known that for OLS estimators, the parameters are asymptotically normal, i.e. for the regression $y_i = \beta_i x_i$,

$$\hat{\beta_i} \sim \mathcal{N}(\beta_i, \sigma^2 (X_i^T X_i)^{-1})$$

Consequently, for any fixed $x_i$, the product $\hat{\beta_i} x_i$ is also normally distributed.

Is there any analogous relationship for the parameters of a logistic regression?

For context, I am looking to give a bound on the probability that the resultant output from a LR is within a certain interval.

Comment: After some more searching – it seems that a viable procedure would be to assume the asymptotic normality of the parameters $\theta$ used in the logistic regression (presuming MLE), compute the corresponding confidence intervals, and then take the inverse logit to get the endpoints in the response scale.

Comment: If someone has more insight into this that would still be greatly appreciated!